# Why, in showing $\cot^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin x}+\sqrt{1-\sin x}}{\sqrt{1+\sin x}-\sqrt{1-\sin x}}=\frac{x}2$, use the constraint $x\in(0,\pi/4)$?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function, constraints

Prove that:
$$\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin{x}}+\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}}{\sqrt{1+\sin{x}}-\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}}\right)=\frac{x}{2}$$

But there is a constraint on $x$ in this problem given in my textbook. It is that $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$.

FYI, I know how to prove this, the proof is not what I'm asking for. I just can't get my head around this constraint.

I know that the principal value branch of $\sin$ function is $\left[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. So I think it has to do with that.

I am also doubting my book, because it has given some weird constraints before as well, but I'm here asking others just to make sure I'm not missing something on this one.

Comment: What do you mean by "I know that the principal value branch of $\sin$ function is $\left[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$"?

Comment: "FYI, I know how to prove this": can you please edit your post to include your proof?

Comment: Just to correct you.. there is no principal value of sin. The thing you are saying is the principal branch of sin inverse function. ALSO what exactly are you asking for in it? Value to x?

Comment: @44yu5h, thanks for correcting, that is what I mean. In this question, I wanna know why their is this constraint on x.

Comment: Again: please insert your proof in your post. Then we can help you to find out what the constraint should be (or you will find it without help).

Comment: @AnneBauval i've added the proof. Just a gentle reminder. Please don't be rude with others :)

Comment: @44yu5h I was not curious for "the" proof (mine is shorter). I was asking the OP to show 1) a minimal effort, 2) personal thoughts which need to be corrected.  Usually on this site, posts which don't receive no answer, or answerers are blamed by moderators.  Gently recalling and motivating the rules is not being rude. Spoon-feeding is not teaching.

Comment: @AnneBauval You're right as well.. what can i say :))

Answer (score 1):

**The proof:**

$\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin{x}}+\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}}{\sqrt{1+\sin{x}}-\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}}\right)$=$\frac{x}{2}$.

LHS = $\cot^{-1}\left(\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin{x}}+\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}}{\sqrt{1+\sin{x}}-\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}}\right)\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+\sin{x}}+\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}}{\sqrt{1+\sin{x}}+\sqrt{1-\sin{x}}}\right)\right)$

$\quad\quad\quad\cot^{-1}\left(\frac{2 + 2|\cos{x}|}{2\sin{x}}\right)$

$\quad\quad\quad \cot^{-1}\left(\frac{1 + |\cos{x}|}{2\sin{(x/2)}\cos{(x/2)}}\right)\quad\quad\left(\frac{1-\cos{x}}{2}= \sin^2{(x/2)}\right) and \left(\frac{1 + \cos{x}}{2}= \cos^2{(x/2)}\right)$

---

So for $[0, π/2]$ it will be $\cos^2{(x/2)}$ and for $[π/2,π]$ it will be $\sin^2{(x/2)}$ because of the mod

for $[0, π/2]$: 
$\quad\quad\quad \cot^{-1}\left(\cot{(x/2)}\right) = x/2$

for $[π/2,π]$: 
$\quad\quad\quad \cot^{-1}\left(\tan{(x/2)}\right) = π/2 - x/2$

The constraint is there because of this essentially and and also at $x = 0$ or $n\pi$ denominator becomes $0$, and possibly to avoid multiple answers (after 2$\pi$)

It really should have been $(0,\pi/2]$ but that is still a superset of $(0,\pi/4)$ so it doesn't really matter. Maybe the question has some more stuffs connected to it? But again it's okay.

**Graph for reference:**
[image]
That peak at $\pi/2$ is $(\pi/2,\pi/4)$
(I used latex for the first time so sorry for bad formatting, using latex is really painful lol)

Comment: That I what I also think, that the given constraint is a subset of $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. I still doubt that this constraint isn't posing any "tight" restrictions.

Comment: @VizDracViz I've checked everything, it does not have any strict requisite of that kind. However, you should take time to clear any doubts that you have.